# MDX - Extract Last 24 hours data

Tags: ssas, mdx

I need to extract last 24 hours data from a cube. Below is the MDX I have written but it doesn't return the data according to current time (system time).

```
SELECT 
  [Date].[Calender-Year_Quarter_Month_Date].[Date] ON ROWS
 ,{[Measures].[Delay In Mintues]} ON COLUMNS
FROM 
(
  SELECT 
      {
          StrToMember
          ("[Date].[Calender-Year_Quarter_Month_Date].[Date].&["
              + 
                Format
                (
                  Now() - 1
                 ,'yyyyMMdd'
                )
            + "]"
          )
        * 
          (
            [Time].[Time-Hour_Time].[Hour].&["+FORMAT(NOW(),"HH")+"]
          : 
            [Time].[Time-Hour_Time].[Hour].&[23].&[23:59]
          )
      }
    + 
      {
          StrToMember
          ("[Date].[Calender-Year_Quarter_Month_Date].[Date].&["
              + 
                Format
                (
                  Now()
                 ,'yyyyMMdd'
                )
            + "]"
          )
        * 
          (
            [Time].[Time-Hour_Time].[Hour].&[0].&[00:00]
          : 
            [Time].[Time-Hour_Time].[Hour].&["+FORMAT(NOW(),"HH")+"]
          )
      } ON COLUMNS
  FROM [Delay Reasons]
);
```

Comment: why do you use a sub-query rather than a `WHERE` clause?

Comment: is `&[00:00]` required at the end of each range?

Answer (score 0):

(note: not tested)

Does this work?

```
SELECT 
  [Date].[Calender-Year_Quarter_Month_Date].[Date] ON ROWS
 ,{[Measures].[Delay In Mintues]} ON COLUMNS
FROM [Delay Reasons]
WHERE 
    {
        StrToMember
        ("[Date].[Calender-Year_Quarter_Month_Date].[Date].&["
            + 
              Format
              (
                Now() - 1
               ,'yyyyMMdd'
              )
          + "]"
        )
      * 
        (
          [Time].[Time-Hour_Time].[Hour].&["+FORMAT(NOW(),"HH")+"]
        : 
          [Time].[Time-Hour_Time].[Hour].&[23].&[23:59]
        )
    }
  + 
    {
        StrToMember
        ("[Date].[Calender-Year_Quarter_Month_Date].[Date].&["
            + 
              Format
              (
                Now()
               ,'yyyyMMdd'
              )
          + "]"
        )
      * 
        (
          [Time].[Time-Hour_Time].[Hour].&[0].&[00:00]
        : 
          StrToMember
          (
            "[Time].[Time-Hour_Time].[Hour].&[" + Format(Now(),"HH") + "].&[00:00]"
          )
        )
    };
```